# I am trying to see if the 100 amp breaker that was feeding my residence can be replaced with 125 Amp-1 AWG Aluminum wire is buried 60'

Tags: electrical

There is 200 Amp service so it had 100 amp service to the residence and 100 amps feeding the shop.  At the shop there is a 60 Amp main so I know there's voltage to spare.  No one has 100 Amp breaker this time of night so I am trying to not burn the wire from the feeder to the residence sub panel.

Comment: Please clarify. What is your question?

Comment: What happened to the existing 100A breaker? Can you post photos of the panels in question?

Answer (score 3):

Running 125A on #1 aluminum wire is *out of the question*.  You need 1/0 aluminum to run 125A.  Even if your meter was provisioned 125A and you were able to take advantage of NEC 310.15(B)(7), you still need 1/0 aluminum for 125A.

Further, **you can't bring a second feeder to the house**, because of NEC 225.30.  **You are only allowed one feeder per building**.  The only exception would be if the main feeder carried utility-only power but the auxiliary feeder was generator-backed-up.  Then you could claim it under 225.30(A).  You would need to make that believable by rearranging panels in both buildings, i.e. fit a generator interlock and inlet in the barn and have it feed a panel full of critical loads.

---

**Wait, are you talking about the size of the "main breaker" in the subpanel?**  Any size you want, sky's the limit.  It's only there to be a disconnect switch.

**The much more important thing is to get PLENTY of breaker spaces**, so you never run out of spaces - that is an expensive problem to have, and a ridiculously cheap problem to avoid.  Feel free to use a 200A/30-space panel in the shop. You *can* feed that with a 100A feeder.

If you're here to get the advice of experts, that's it. Go BIG BIG BIG on the shop subpanel.

---

**Or are you talking about the feeder breaker that lives in the main panel?**  Nope, you can only run 100A on #1 aluminum wire.  That's right Table 310.15(B)(16).

OK so they're out-of-stock for 100A breakers (~$45)... I bet they have loads of 60A ($10) or 50A ($10). Just get one of those.  That's *vanishingly unlikely* to trip for typical "out at the shop" loads.

Most people who choose 100A for their shops are *wildly* over-provisioning the shop.  The logic is "wire is cheap" which I actually agree with, but that's often inflamed with a great misunderstanding of how to add up branch circuits to arrive at a needed feeder size.   Unless you actually own a Tesla Fast Charger (100A breaker), it would be virtually impossible to trip a 60A breaker with consumer or prosumer shop equipment.

Plus, 60A breakers are cheap. You're not really pouring good money after bad like you would with a 125A ($70) breaker.

Comment: Great answer Harp. Yet my shop is provisioned with a 100 amp breaker, bc I have a 3 HP dust collector and a 7.5 HP drum sander that I need to run at the same time.   Not only that. if there are other helpers in the shop running the 5 HP planer or 3 HP table saw, I need that amount of power. I realize that even though I'm a serious hobbyist and have gone beyond what most residential, or "prosumer", going up to the capacity of the cable with a slightly more expensive breaker is the right answer IMHO. It does bother me that the OP said "voltage to spare" when it's really about amperage.